# Cannot specified a device when running calabash-ios with Xamarin

Tags: ios, ruby, device, calabash, calabash-ios

I have an issue that appears on one computer but on the other it is working fine.

I’m running calabash-ios with Xamarin and get the error:

```
`No device_target was specified and did not detect a connected device. Set a device_target option in the relaunch method. (RuntimeError)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.0/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:683:in default_uia_strategy'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.14.0/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:626:in relaunch'`
```

I ran `xcrun instruments -s devices` and got the below list:

```
`…
iPhone 6 (9.0) [9E580CB5-8F55-43B5-AC50-05C6C38BC4E0]
iPhone 6 (9.0) + Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [C1326499-01E6-4EC5-9AF5-477A745C0089]
iPhone 6 Plus (8.3) [8BFA71F1-65B2-43C3-BDC6-7EF255C000F8]
…`
```

then:

```
`APP_BUNDLE_PATH=”<project path>/<file>.app”`
```

And then:

```
`DEVICE_TARGET="iPhone 6 (9.0)" cucumber`
```

On one computer it launched the simulator and ran the app, but on the other one it get the above error.

Any idea what I missed and where to start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your Test Cloud Agent to at least 0.16.2 which is compatible with iOS 9 and Xcode 7.  I think this is the cause of the error.

I believe there is a 0.16.4 TCA release on the horizon and 0.17.0 is not far behind.

> re: capital letters.

I think I see the problem now.

```
$ MY_VAR="Hey!"
$ echo $MY_VAR
"" <== the empty string

$ MY_VAR="Hey!" echo $MY_VAR
Hey!

$ export MY_VAR="Hey!"
$ echo $MY_VAR
Hey!

$ APP=/path/to/Your.app DEVICE_TARGET="iPhone 6 (9.0)" cucumber
```

APP and APP_BUNDLE_PATH are equivalent.

Comment: My Test Cloud Agent is 16.2, but my xcode is 7.0. 
Updating it now to 7.1 and i will let you know. 
Thx!!

Comment: The 0.16.4 TCA has been released.

Comment: The xcode now is 7.1.1 and the TCA is 16.2 (couldn't find 16.4), but still get this error

Comment: found the issue - somehow it doesn't take capital letters.
I tried with device_target=... and the error gone.
now i have a new error - Info.plist' does not exist - could not read. - event that it is appears in the app package

Comment: update - updated the calabash-ios to 16.4 and it fixed the plist issue - thx!!!!!!!!!